# Function declaration conditioned on a used library version?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following problem: say I'm using library `Foo` and there's a function `bar` that I use in my personal library. However, in an upcoming release, the function definition of `bar` is going to change. For example,

`bar(int first, int second, int third)`

will become

`bar(int first, int newSecond, int second, int third)`

It would be beneficial to maintain backwards compatibility in my case so I'm wondering if it's possible to define my functions conditioned on the library version

My original code:

```
int myFoo(int first, int second, int third){
    auto something = bar(first, second, third);
    ....
}
```

and the new function might be something like

```
int myFoo(int first, int second, int third){
    auto newSecond = X;
    auto something = bar(first, newSecond, second, third);
    ....
}
```

In python I could do something like

```
int myFoo(int first, int second, int third){
    if Foo.version == "old":
        auto something = bar(first, second, third);
    else:
        auto newSecond = X;
        auto something = bar(first, newSecond, second, third);
    ....
}
```

but how might I accomplish the same in C++? Would using an `#IF ...` work? I Googled around but the results weren't particularly useful as I don't really know the right terms to look up (happy to learn some new terms)

Comment: What library? Does it define version macros?

Comment: The library is [PALISADE-development](https://gitlab.com/palisade/palisade-development) and it does have some code which allows you to grab the version number (if I understand the question right) [version.h](https://gitlab.com/palisade/palisade-development/-/blob/master/src/core/include/version.h#L42)

Comment: I guess `#if` would be the way to go then.  I see no other.  Update: looking at `version.h`, you might have to do a bit of grubbing around to figure out what macro to test.

Comment: Hmm, @PaulSanders do you happen to have any resources handy? When I google conditional function declaration all I get are "here's how to use conditionals in C++"

Comment: You probably want to do something like `#if THE_APPROPRIATE_MACRO >= 5`, where `THE_APPROPRIATE_MACRO` is numeric (and not a string).  Link: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0.1/cpp_4.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to go about this.

The first that comes to mind would be to use preprocessor directives:

```
#define OLD_VERSION // Can be set in code or when you compile the code

int myFoo(int first, int second, int third){
    #ifdef OLD_VERSION
        auto something = bar(first, second, third);
    #else
        auto newSecond = X;
        auto something = bar(first, newSecond, second, third);
    ....
    #endif
}
```

Alternatively, you could wrap the bar function and use function overloading and depending on what parameters you pass in, the appropriate function will be called:

```
int myFoo(int first, int second, int third) { }
int myFoo(int first, int newSecond, int second, int third){ }
```

Comment: Hmmm.  The second suggestion is clever, but dangerous.  And in any case, you still need a `#if` to decide which overload to call.

Comment: @PaulSanders Agreed, the 2nd one is quite dependent on the rest of the implementation so `#if/#ifdef` are probably the way to go, especially if you can the library already provides the versions

Comment: Yes, the library headers providing an appropriate version macro is the key thing here.  The OP will have to hunt that down.